# How to replace a comma separated value in table column with user input value oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in oracle with a column with comma separated values. What i need is when a user enters a value and if that value is present in any of the rows, it should be removed.
eg.

#### COL

123,234
56,123

If user enters 123, the 1st column should have only 234 and second row should have only 56.
How do we do this in oracle??
Please help
Thanks

Comment: do you always have a maximumn of two values per row ? btw if you add SQL tag to your question im sure it will help

Comment: There might even be single, double ot multiple values in that column and not necessarily two.

Answer (score 3):

```
delete from yourtable t
where
  instr(','||t.col||',', '123') > 0
```

You can replace '123' with a parameter if you like.

But a better way would be not to store comma separated values, and create a detail table instead. If you need to look for a specific value within a comma separated list, you cannot make use of indices, amongst other limitations.

[edit]
Misunderstood the question. You meant this:

```
update YourTable t
set
  t.col = substr(substr(replace(','||t.col||',', ',123,', ','), 2), -2)
where
  instr(','||t.col||',', '123') > 0
```

- Add ',' before and after to match items at the beginning or end of the value.
- Replace using the value ',123,' (within comma's) to prevent accidentally matching 1234 too.
- Use substr twice to remove the first and last character (the added commas)
- Use instr in the where to prevent updating records that don't need to be updated (better performance).

Comment: This would delete the entire record - he only wants to remove the specified value from the comma delimited list.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
UPDATE t
SET col = REPLACE(REPLACE(col, '&variable', ''), ',', '') FROM t ;
```